# SQL Trigger that prevents changing a value (SSN)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I got this table named `Professor` with these columns:

```
SSN char(10) primary key not null,
profname varchar(100),
status varchar(20),
salary int
```

I need a trigger to prevent changing the **SSN** of any given professor, raising an error message saying

> 'You cannot change the value of a SSN.'

Any help?

Comment: What did you try? And what RDMS do you use?

Comment: Am on SQL Server 2012. Actually, I'm totally out on this.
I've just started learning triggers in school and we've been doing simpler ones I think like changing the value of the salary after inserting a new record, but this type of trigger that prevents updating, haven't done anything like it.

Comment: Take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx  .

Answer (score 1):

You could admittedly write an after trigger to do that (the specifics are very dependent on the database, so you'd need to provide more information).

That said, think twice about whether it's a good idea or not.

For instance, what if a user enters his SSN and makes a typo? Should he be stuck with an incorrect SSN? Should your staff be unable to change the SSN for him without resorting to the DB admin to temporarily disable the trigger?

Even the wildest things in a DB occasionally change, including stable-looking things like surrogate keys (occasionally happens when you're merging duplicate user entries).

Comment: This is just for testing purposes, I've got an exam coming up soon, and am practicing triggers, and this question is in an exercise in my book.

Comment: In that case, take a peek at this for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job perfectly, but guess I was right, I haven't done anything like this before.

Comment: Basically I agree with you, but if the trigger is for UPDATE only, the DBA could be spared. The row could simply be deleted, then inserted back with a new SSN.

Comment: @AndriyM: but then, I'd expect the delete to cascade delete every related record, no? :-) I'm unfamiliar with SQL Server, but I imagine it allows, like Postgres, to `alter table ... disable trigger ...`.

Comment: It does support `alter table...disable trigger`. I was merely pointing out that if the issue was simply a typo in the (presumably just entered) SSN, one wouldn't require the help of the DBA (to toggle the trigger), because one could just delete/insert the row (if it had just been inserted, no related rows in other tables would be there at the time).